# Cannot Select List View Item Twice

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am having an issue with selecting list view items twice in a row. So when I select one item it loads another list. This is not a problem but when I click back to go back to the previous list view I am no longer able to click the same list view item.
I have done some reading and there seems to be an idea of 'de-selecting' the list view item at some point in the code so being able to select the same item again.
The selection is done using the MVVM model so the code that handles the selection etc.

```
 // bound to list items on front end, reacts to tap on each item
 // and loads route information for the route that is selected

    RouteInfo _selected_item;
    public RouteInfo RouteLabelSelected
    {
        get { return _selected_item; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selected_item)) return;
            _selected_item = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RouteLabelSelected));
            OpenRoutePage(_selected_item.ID);

        }

    }
```

The OpenRoutePage method simply opens the next list view, as I said this works fine.
I have attached some images to better illustrate the problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, forgive the artwork.

Answer (score 5):

in your ItemSelected event handler, you need to set SelectedItem = null

```
protected void ItemSelected(object source, ItemSelectedEventArgs args) {

  // do whatever actions on selected item here

  // then reset SelectedItem
  ((ListView)source).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: How does this fit in with MVVM? The actions are bound to the view model. So, how would I fit this in with the code snippet I posted?

Comment: How do you have your ItemSelected event wired up?  Alternately, you could just reset the SelectedItem whenever OnAppearing fires.

Comment: The item selected is wired through binding in xaml that 'speaks' to the code snippet I posted.
As for the OnAppearing method I tried that but when trying to navigate back to the first list view it throws a null object exception.

Comment: I think the only way of doing it is from code behind. This is exactly how it's shown in the Xamarin documentation  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/

Comment: Or try using the ItemTapped event instead, it will fire even if the item was previously selected.

Comment: Right. I will look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create to different event handlers to solve the issue, namely ItemTapped and ItemSelected event handlers. The ItemSelected event is triggered first on clicked/tapped and then it triggers the ItemTapped event. On first tap/click on a listview item, the ItemTapped event is triggered twice after triggering the ItemSelected event. To overcome this issue, you can attach both event handlers and simply set/clear a boolean property.

Example:

```
private bool _isSelected;

private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   _isSelected = true;
}

private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
   if(!_isSelected)
   {
      //do work here
   }
   _isSelected = false;
}
```

Here, first the ItemSelected event is triggered and the variable _isSelected is set. Then the ItemTapped event is triggered twice. The condition in the ItemTapped event prevents the user code from executing in the first call and then allows the code execution in the second call.